# use environment variables in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a a eclipse CDT project using a Cross GCC toolchain. The path of the cross compiler has to be set in the toolchain settings: C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross Settings -> Path.

Because of sharing this project with other people, the path to the cross compiler should be in an environment variable which I called LINUX_DEVKIT_PATH.

I defined LINUX_DEVKIT_PATH as an environment variable and used "${LINUX_DEVKIT_PATH}/bin" in the C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross Settings -> Path field. But with this settings the compiler couldn't be found.
I also tried to used C/C++ Build -> Environment -> Select... to add the variable to the list. The environment variable is found and appears in the list with the origin User: Config.

Comment: I think you will have to add this as a environment variable on the machine itself...Meaning that it is defined on the machine and not eclipse(eclipse will just access the definition)

Comment: have you tried to use them with $(ENV_VAR_NAME)? The makefile could be able to handle this. Once I avoided that eclipse added the workspace path with /$(ENV_VAR_NAME), so eclipse thought it is an absolute path.

Comment: It look like there is a bug on the Eclipse. To force the variables into the cross settings' path, you need to add the '/' in front of the variables. eg: /${LINUX_DEVKIT_PATH}/bin. Check the project -> properties -> c/c++ build -> environment -> PATH - cross settings' path will affect this PATH.

Answer (score 1):

In your Eclipse you can set the environment variables and values to use when an application runs.

To set environment variables:

1. In the C/C++ Projects view, select a project.
2. Click Run > Run or Run > Debug.
3. In the Configurations box, expand C/C++ Local.
4. Select a run or debug configuration.
5. Click the Environment tab..
6. Do one of the following:

   - To create a new environment variable, click New.
   - To import an environment variable, click Import.
   - To edit an existing environment variable, select an item from the list and click Edit.
   - To remove an existing environment variable, select an item from the list and click Remove.
7. Type a name in the Name box.
8. Type a value in the Value box.
9. Click Run or do the following, as required:

To specify the execution arguments that an application uses and to specify the working directory for a run configuration, see Specifying execution arguments.
To select a debugger to use when debugging an application, see Selecting a debugger
To specify the location of source files used when debugging a C or C++ application, see Specifying the location of source files
To specify where the run configuration is stored, how you access it, and the perspective to open when running an application, see Specifying the location of the run configuration.

Good luck my friend.And if this post answers your question don't forget to accept it as an answer.

Comment: unfortunately this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I will add more details to my description.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

- I've created environment variable `MY_CROSS_BIN` with my contents of "Path" Cross Settings
- 'Selected' it into project (project -> properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment)
- I've edited PATH variable in same properties window to point to: `${MY_CROSS_BIN}${PathDelimiter}${PATH}`
- I've cleaned (left empty) Path settings in C/C++ Build -> Settings

seems to be working... but it cripples Eclipse automagic discovery (includes no longer are found etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Eclipse continues to improve, and yet ...
All answers to Eclipse problems will come in the form "this worked for me".

***This worked for me:***

```
Create a project:   
File-> New -> Makefile Project With Existing Code
+ Browse to existing code location
+ Toolchain: Cross ARM GCC
<Finish>
```

There is your new project. Fine

Try to build - On the console it appears that the command 'all' is attempted to run. (Hope your program in your path 'all' does not rm -f ~/)

NOW Open the project properties and click though all the C/C++ build options.
Don't change them, just click on them. Hit OK to exit.

Now, try build again:
Voila! it works:

make all is executed.

(Eclipse is frustrating.)